# can i register for neobux from my windows form application

Tags: c#

i tired this namespace Adds

i don't know how to connect my project with neobux server.

```
{
partial class Register
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label5 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label6 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label7 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.checkBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
        this.checkBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.textBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.textBox3 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.textBox4 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.textBox5 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.textBox6 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.textBox7 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this.label1.AutoSize = true;
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(33, 62);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(61, 13);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.label1.Text = "Username :";
        // 
        // label2
        // 
        this.label2.AutoSize = true;
        this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(33, 125);
        this.label2.Name = "label2";
        this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(59, 13);
        this.label2.TabIndex = 1;
        this.label2.Text = "Password :";
        // 
        // label3
        // 
        this.label3.AutoSize = true;
        this.label3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(33, 146);
        this.label3.Name = "label3";
        this.label3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(120, 13);
        this.label3.TabIndex = 2;
        this.label3.Text = "Password Confirmation :";
        // 
        // label4
        // 
        this.label4.AutoSize = true;
        this.label4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(33, 192);
        this.label4.Name = "label4";
        this.label4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(38, 13);
        this.label4.TabIndex = 3;
        this.label4.Text = "Email :";
        // 
        // label5
        // 
        this.label5.AutoSize = true;
        this.label5.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(33, 245);
        this.label5.Name = "label5";
        this.label5.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(51, 13);
        this.label5.TabIndex = 4;
        this.label5.Text = "Raferrer :";
        // 
        // label6
        // 
        this.label6.AutoSize = true;
        this.label6.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(33, 285);
        this.label6.Name = "label6";
        this.label6.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(59, 13);
        this.label6.TabIndex = 5;
        this.label6.Text = "Birth Year :";
        // 
        // label7
        // 
        this.label7.AutoSize = true;
        this.label7.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(33, 340);
        this.label7.Name = "label7";
        this.label7.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(93, 13);
        this.label7.TabIndex = 6;
        this.label7.Text = "Verification Code :";
        // 
        // checkBox1
        // 
        this.checkBox1.AutoSize = true;
        this.checkBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(33, 390);
        this.checkBox1.Name = "checkBox1";
        this.checkBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(395, 30);
        this.checkBox1.TabIndex = 7;
        this.checkBox1.Text = "I declare to have read, understood, and accecpted the Terms of Services And\r\nPriv" +
            "acy Policy.";
        this.checkBox1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.BottomLeft;
        this.checkBox1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // checkBox2
        // 
        this.checkBox2.AutoSize = true;
        this.checkBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(33, 444);
        this.checkBox2.Name = "checkBox2";
        this.checkBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(291, 17);
        this.checkBox2.TabIndex = 8;
        this.checkBox2.Text = "I give my consent to the processing of my personal data.";
        this.checkBox2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(378, 490);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 9;
        this.button1.Text = "continue";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // textBox1
        // 
        this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 59);
        this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
        this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(353, 20);
        this.textBox1.TabIndex = 10;
        // 
        // textBox2
        // 
        this.textBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(99, 120);
        this.textBox2.Name = "textBox2";
        this.textBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(354, 20);
        this.textBox2.TabIndex = 11;
        // 
        // textBox3
        // 
        this.textBox3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(160, 145);
        this.textBox3.Name = "textBox3";
        this.textBox3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(293, 20);
        this.textBox3.TabIndex = 12;
        // 
        // textBox4
        // 
        this.textBox4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(78, 187);
        this.textBox4.Name = "textBox4";
        this.textBox4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(375, 20);
        this.textBox4.TabIndex = 13;
        // 
        // textBox5
        // 
        this.textBox5.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(91, 243);
        this.textBox5.Name = "textBox5";
        this.textBox5.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(362, 20);
        this.textBox5.TabIndex = 14;
        // 
        // textBox6
        // 
        this.textBox6.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(98, 282);
        this.textBox6.Name = "textBox6";
        this.textBox6.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(355, 20);
        this.textBox6.TabIndex = 15;
        // 
        // textBox7
        // 
        this.textBox7.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(133, 338);
        this.textBox7.Name = "textBox7";
        this.textBox7.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(320, 20);
        this.textBox7.TabIndex = 16;
        // 
        // Register
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(498, 536);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox7);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox6);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox5);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox4);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox3);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.checkBox2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.checkBox1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label7);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label6);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label5);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label4);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label3);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.Name = "Register";
        this.Text = "Register";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label3;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label4;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label5;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label6;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label7;
    private System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox checkBox1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox checkBox2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox3;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox4;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox5;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox6;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox7;

}
}
```

[i created this application for register for neobux](https://github.com/AkshayIT423/Register/archive/master.zip)

i don't know how to connect my project with neobux server.

Comment: Do you have the relevant code that's causing a problem? That code is just the designer code. Also, I don't recommend linking directly to files; it's a good way to pass around malware. Instead, just link to the repo. No one's going to click that .zip file.

Comment: There is absolutely no information in this question which would allow us to assist you. We don't know anything about this "neobux" thing (don't assume we know your random product/API, instead, provide a link to documentation), we don't know what code you've written in order to try and "connect" to it, we don't know what sort of "connection" you are aiming for or what result you expect, and we don't know what problem you're having when you do so. If you don't even know where to start with your requirement then please a) consult the product docs, and b) tell us where to find them too.

Comment: P.S. please also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for guidance on improving the quality of your question and providing a useful example of your code. Thanks.